# Finding the sum of $\sum_{k=n}^N {N\choose k}x^k(1-x)^{N-k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

I am working on a combinatorial problem and want to evaluate the following sum:

\begin{equation}
S_n = \sum_{k=n}^N {N\choose k} x^k(1-x)^{N-k},
\end{equation}
where $N=2n-1$ and $|x|\leq1$.

I tried the following

\begin{equation}
S_n = \sum_{k=n}^N {N\choose k} x^k(1-x)^{N-k}\\
= \sum_{j=0}^{N-n} {N\choose N-j} x^{N-j}(1-x)^{j}\\
= x^N\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} {N\choose j} \left(\frac{(1-x)}{x}\right)^{j}\\
= x^N\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} {2n-1\choose j} z^{j},\\
\end{equation}
where I used the substitution $z=\frac{1-x}{x}$. This last results looks a bit like the binomial theorem, but the binomial coefficient is not right. I am not sure if its possible to get a closed form (maybe containing some special functions) of this sum.

Comment: The expression can be recognized as $P(X\geq n)$ where $X$ is a random variable having binomial distribution with parameters $2n-1$ and $x$. AFAIK there is no closed expression for it (unless $x=0.5$ because then $P(X\geq n)=P(X\leq n-1)=0.5$).

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. Thank you very much, somehow I didn't recognize it sooner.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{k=n}^{2 n - 1} {2n-1\choose k} p^k (1 - p)^{2 n - 1 - k} 
\\
=& \frac{2^{2 n - 1} (n - \frac12)! (1 - p)^{n - 1} p^n {}_{2}F_1(1, 1 - n; n + 1; \frac p{p - 1})}{\sqrt{\pi} n!}
\\
=& {2 n - 1\choose n} (1 - p)^{n - 1} p^n {}_2F_1(1, 1 - n; n + 1; \frac p{p - 1})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

${}_2F_1(a, b; c; x)$ is the hypergeometric function. [reference](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BPower%5Bp%2Ck%5DPower%5B%5C%2840%291-p%5C%2841%29%2C2n-1-k%5D%5C%28123%292n-1%5Cchoosek%5C%28125%29%2C%7Bk%2Cn%2C2n-1%7D%5D)